# Programmatically Accessing iPod Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How could I select and play a song in an iPhone user's library using objective-c? Thank you so much! I couldn't find how using Apple's documentation or Google.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant class for finding available songs is [MPMediaQuery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). There are a bunch of filters you can use to get a subset of the iTunes library returned. You'll end up with an NSArray of [MPMediaItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). You can use the valueForProperty: method with the MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL property to get a URL that references the item.

They won't generally be normal file URLs, but they are URLs that the AV Foundation is able to use so an instance of [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) should be able to play a song.